# Как настроить в cron выполнение просроченных задач

Tags: cron

Есть задача в кроне например на 8.20. В это время комп выключен. Как сделать, чтобы когда он включится опять, задача исполнилась?

Answer (score 2):

Идея такова добавить в скрипт (назовем его cronjob.sh) обновление некоторого вспомогательного файла, например, last

```
touch last
```

Дальше добавить в скрипт автозапуска тот же скрипт, что и в крон и выполнять его, если last обновлялся позднее, чем, например, 1 час тому назад

```
touch -d '-1 hour' referenceif [ reference -nt last ]; then    # Выполнить скрипт из cron'а    /home/user/cronjob.shfi
```

В скрипт автозапуска на разных Linux по-разному добавляется, например, для Ubuntu это строка в исполняемом файле `/etc/init.d/local`

```
sudo echo "/home/user/autostart.sh" >> /etc/init.d/localsudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/localsudo update-rc.d local defaults 80
```

Comment: Ну, если уже есть cron - можно не трогать все эти rc.local, а юзать директиву @reboot в самом cron-файле

Answer (score 1):

есть же anacron https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron и другие команды отложеного запуска.